# Access to ViewChildren list after NgFor

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I woul like to access all the viewChildren after one ng for to a component, for example:

```
<component #item *ngFor="let item of items" [parameter1]="item.parameter1" [parameter2]="item.parameter2"></component>
```

Now, i have a ViewChildren like this:

```
@ViewChildren('item') item: QueryList<Item>
```

but when i console.log him, it only appears one and i would like to have the reference of every  of the ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to changes to get notified when the queried elements change:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.item.toArray());
  this.item.changes.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.item.toArray());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this **.toArray**, it works :

```
@ViewChildren('item') item;

this.item.toArray()
```